# How to cancel rememberUpdatedState when composition is disposed

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm pretty new to Jetpack Compose and ran into an oddity with `rememberUpdatedState`.
I have Composable Screen, which has a `navUp` parameter to go up in the navigation tree and a `saveWithViewmodelScope` parameter to save the user-input using the viewmodel scope rather than using the composable scope, it also takes a callback to run after saving is completed.

Here is a shortened version of the code:

```
@Composable
fun SomeScreen(
    navUp: () -> Unit,
    save: suspend () -> Unit,
    saveUseViewmodelScope: (() -> Unit) -> Unit
) {
    val callback by rememberUpdatedState(navUp)
    Column {
        val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        Button(
            onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    save()
                    navUp()
                }
            },
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "save with composable scope"
            )
        }
        Button(
            onClick = {
                saveUseViewmodelScope(callback)
            },
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "save with viewmodel scope"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I press save, I would like to wait until saving is done and then navigate away.
Therefore I keep a reference to the latest `navUp` using `rememberUpdatedState`.
It works, but if I leave the screen before saving is done, the callback will still be called, since the coroutine scope is bound to the ViewModel, not the Composable.
I would like to modify the callback to do nothing when the Composable was disposed while the long running task was running, but couldn't find a way to do that.
How would I do that ?

The other version in this example which uses the Composable scope does work as expected, but saving will be interrupted when the Composable gets disposed.
There might be legitimate use cases where I would want to ALWAYS finish saving and OPTIONALLY call a callback if the Composable has not been disposed yet.

I have tried this workaround here and it seems to work, but it feels very clunky:

```
    var disposed by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    DisposableEffect(true) {
        onDispose {
            disposed = true
        }
    }
    val callback by rememberUpdatedState {
        if (!disposed) navUp()
    }
```

So my question is, how would I do that in an elegant way ?

Comment: Actually coroutine should be cancelled, when `rememberCoroutineScope` is removed from the view tree. Check out [this sample](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/607bedc83f2df0645647b8f055eab09a) - I run a scope with button press, then remove it from the view tree with a switch, and logging stops.

Comment: @PylypDukhov correct, that one does get cancelled. The issue is with `saveUseViewmodelScope` check the button below that one.